# PHP массив размером 200мб

Tags: php, массивы

**Такая задача возникла:** Из БД сделал экспорт таблицы в массив `PHP`. Так же в интернет магазине есть около 50К товарных позиций. Таблицу которую экспортировал с другого интернет магазина, и соответственно названия полей другие. Нужно написать скрипт, который будет нужные поля из массива присваивать товарным позициям. У товаров и массива есть общее свойство "артикул" - значение которых совпадают. Нужно перебирать все товары, у i-го товара брать артикул и искать его массиве и присваивать значения из массива товару.

---

**Теперь вопрос:** Файл с массивом в отдельном файле, размер его огромный, каким образом его подключать в скрипт, что бы было легче работать (быстрее работал скрипт), через `include` или `require`? Так же придется поменять таймаут выполнения скрипта. Получится ли вообще работать с этим массивом, или лучше делать `sql` запросы? Что можете посоветовать? Только сама БД находится на другом сервере и работы будут производится на другом.

Comment: с базой легче можнеже проверки и выборку прям на базе сделать

Comment: Ну, конечно можно и целиком подключать, если памяти много и ограничения памяти в php.ini достаточно высоки, но учитывайте что в памяти этот массив будет больше, чем размер файла в разы. Лучше реализуйте потоковую обработку

Comment: У консольных скриптов время работы не ограничено. Работы явно одноразовые. Какая разница, за 5 минут скрипт отработает, или за 10?

Comment: @aat А "массив" который в файле у вас в каком формате ? как вы его разворачиваете собственно в массив в php ?

Answer (score 1):

Без разницы, как будет цепляться файл рнр, памяти съест порядком. Лучше вернуться этапом раньше в сторону БД. Если я правильно понимаю, уже есть БД, в которой 2 таблицы - старые (old) и новые товары (new).

Проще всего будет sql запросом:

```
UPDATE new JOIN old ON new.art=old.articul SET
new.name = old.naimenovanie,
new.desc = old.description,
new.count = old.count+new.count
```

вот базовый пример, сольет по артикулам, любые поля напрямую можно будет прописывать - что и куда.

Answer (score 1):

Если запустить нужно единоразово для обработки, проще запустить как cli-скрипт, предварительно увеличив память для php:
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

Хотя если удалось сделать экспорт, то памяти и так должно хватать.

`include` или `require` - не имеет значения.

Answer (score 0):

В целом без разницы каким способом подключать, памяти уйдёт много. Если будет ошибка allowed memory size то помещайте один или оба массива в базу, в заранее подготовленные две таблицы и работайте с ними уже построчно. Помедленнее будет из-за запросов и обновлений но существенно меньше требования к памяти будут.